# How to get top N Ethereum accounts by balance through web3.js?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I can get balance of particular account, byt I'm wondering are there any way in web3.js to get first N ethereum accounts sorted by their Ethereum balances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. You'd have to write a script that scans each transaction from each block on the chain, collect the list of addresses by looking at the `to` for each transaction, filter out contract address from the address collection, then retrieve the balance of the remaining addresses and sort. The script isn't particularly difficult to write, but it will probably take a long time to run.

Comment: Thank you, as I understand it would be usefull to make use of distributed computing to achieve it, something like map-reduce, how do you think?

Comment: There are many ways you can do it. Certainly nothing wrong with a Spark/MR type solution. You can even go with a simple RDBMS. Once your data is bootstrapped, you can setup listeners to process new blocks as they are added to the chain. The transaction rate on the blockchain is still very low making distributing computing kind of overkill. But, again, nothing wrong with that approach.